# How would I say that the food I ate "didn't agree with me"?

Tags: words

Is there a term that I can use to say that the food was not agreeable when I ate it. It didn't make me feel good.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By far the most-often used verb would be 「合{あ}う」.  Its negative form is 「合わない」.

We often say things like:

- 「そのラーメンは私には合わなかった。」

  Expresses general dislike without specifying the reasons.  Just sounds "nicer" than saying it was terrible.  It can imply that others might like it though you did not yourself.
- 「そのラーメンは私のお腹{なか}には合わなかった。」

  Ingredients were tough on your stomach.  You got "sick" from eating it.  This phrase says nothing about how the food tasted to you.  You may have even liked it while eating it.
- 「そのラーメンは私の舌{した}には合わなかった。」

  Did not like the taste (but it did not make you feel sick).  舌 means "tongue".  「舌」 can be replaced by 「口」 and the meaning stays the same.